# locale.defaut().country не выводит , то что должно

Tags: android, kotlin, locale

у меня есть переменная которая  должна выводить "RU", но почему-то этого не происходит

```
val countryName = Locale.getDefault().country
```

Если использовать данную переменную в новом проекте , то он работает , но когда я использую ее в своем коде

```
fun getBookmarks(): ArrayList<Bookmark> {
val countryName = Locale.getDefault().country 

val arr = arrayListOf<Bookmark>()
 
    when (countryName){
    "RU" -> {arr add()
```

условие when не выполняется.
Я так же пробовал сделать это через equals, но это тоже не помогает

Comment: А что выводит-то? В консоль ее.

Answer (score 0):

Текущий язык системы вычисляется вот так:

```
String locale_def;
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ){
    locale_def = LocaleList.getDefault().get(0).getLanguage();
} else {
    locale_def = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , это мне подошло , но мне нужен был язык , для того чтобы по нему потом получить страну. В данный момент мне этого хватит, но в будущем есои появятся страны с одним языком , например: канада и сша. Нужно уже что-то менять